# Where is the invalid relational operator in this statement?

Tags: sql

Where is the invalid relational operator in this statement?

```
(SELECT (a.FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_GRNT_YR) FROM  a.FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL
WHERE FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_COAS_CODE = a.FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_COAS_CODE  
AND  FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_GRNT_CODE = a.FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_GRNT_CODE  
AND  FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_FUND_CODE = a.FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_FUND_CODE  
AND  FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_ORGN_CODE = a.FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_ORGN_CODE  
AND  FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_ACCT_CODE = a.FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_ACCT_CODE  
AND  FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_PROG_CODE = a.FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_PROG_CODE  
AND  FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_ACTV_CODE = a.FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_ACTV_CODE  
AND  FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_LOCN_CODE = a.FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_LOCN_CODE)
```

Comment: `a.FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL` 3 part name - database.schema.table/view and in WHERE condition `a.FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_COAS_CODE` is also 3 part name - it should  be 4 part with actual column

Comment: What's the specific database? Sybase/SAP, SQL Server, DB2?

Comment: Why is this query enclosed in parentheses? Is it a subquery inside another query?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to join the tables which i guess are `FIMSMGR` and `FRRGRNL` if I simply go by the names you are using in where clause

```
    (SELECT 
     (FIMSMGR.FRRGRNL_GRNT_YR) 
     FROM  FIMSMGR a, FRRGRNL b
        -- added
     WHERE 
    a.FRRGRNL_COAS_CODE = 
  b.FRRGRNL_COAS_CODE  
   AND  
   a.FRRGRNL_GRNT_CODE 
   = b.FRRGRNL_GRNT_CODE  
   AND  
    a.FRRGRNL_FUND_CODE = 
    b.FRRGRNL_FUND_CODE  
    AND  
    a.FRRGRNL_ORGN_CODE = 
    b.FRRGRNL_ORGN_CODE  
   AND  
   a.FRRGRNL_ACCT_CODE = 
   b.FRRGRNL_ACCT_CODE  
   AND  
   a.FRRGRNL_PROG_CODE = 
   b.FRRGRNL_PROG_CODE  
  AND  
  a.FRRGRNL_ACTV_CODE = 
   b.FRRGRNL_ACTV_CODE  
  AND  
 a.FRRGRNL_LOCN_CODE = 
 b.FRRGRNL_LOCN_CODE)
```